# Is there any difference between (ptr + i)->Func() and &ptr[i].Func()

Tags: c++, performance, hpc

Or both of them are equal? ptr is a pointer to an array of structs.

**UPD:** Thank you all for the response. I'm sorry, I misspelled the syntax. What I'm trying to compare is `(ptr + i)->Func()` vs `(&ptr[i])->Func()`. I'm confused with a `&` operator as it is supposed to return address of a variable. Doesn't it result into one more operation of taking that address?

Comment: You meant `&ptr[i]->Func()`, right?

Comment: This assumes that the return value is something you should be taking the address of, and not some kind of temporary.

Comment: seems more likely to me that the `&` in the title is bogus

Comment: Sorry guys, I misspelled the code, it was (&ptr[i])->Func(); I've updated my question.

Comment: Since `ptr[i]` is the same as `*(ptr+i)`, `&ptr[i]` is the same as `&*(ptr+i)` which is the same as `(ptr+i)`. There's no performance issue here, they all parse down to the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably mean `&ptr[i]->Func()`, otherwise your expressions do not have identical functionality.

According to C++ standard, adding a value of pointer type to a value of integral type produces a pointer of the same type as original at the offset equal to the value of integral type. The same value is produced by taking an address of `ptr[offset]`, so the two are identical. Moreover, the order of addition does not matter, so all of the expressions below do the same thing, and should produce identical executable codes:

```
&ptr[i]
(ptr+i)
(i+ptr)
&(i[ptr]) // <<== Don't do this!
```

The last item is there only as a curiosity. Do not use this construct in code outside of programming puzzles.

Answer (score 8):

`(ptr + i)->Func()` is equivalent to `ptr[i].Func()`.

And due to operator precedence, `&ptr[i].Func()` is equivalent to `&(ptr[i].Func())`, that is it takes an address of the return value of `Func()`.

Comment: It's the reverse: `ptr[i]` is equivalent to `*(ptr + i)`.

Comment: @black and `(*X).Func` is equivalent to `X->Func`

Comment: @black so they are equivalent, it's a commutative relation

Comment: @black Symmetry is one of the conditions for equivalence.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference. `ptr[i]` is guaranteed by the standard to be completely equivalent to `*(ptr+i)`. The former is usually easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that struct or class has Func function. 
So access to function by address is the same that access to the field.
In my opinion it's just address arithmetic differences.
So? both of them are equal.